# Toggle different components from multiple buttons (nextjs)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, next.js

I'm trying to build an component that render different components based on which button the user clicks.

this is what the "pages" are:

`

```
    const navigation = [
      { name: "EOQ", return: "<EOQgraph />" },
      { name: "ROP", href: "<ROPgraph />" },
      { name: "Table", href: "<Table />" },
      { name: "ROC+SS", href: "<ROCSSgraph />" },
      { name: "Table+SS", href: "<TableSS />" },
    ]
```

`

This is the function and the UseState that needs to receive the key (Not all of the components are in yet):

`

```
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState('')

const wantedGraph = (value) => {

    switch (value){
      case  "EOQ":
        return setToggle(<EOQgraph />);
      case  "ROP":
        return setToggle(<ROPgraph />);
```

`

And the return that uses a .map to display all the buttons:
`

```
        return(
            <div>
                {navigation.map((item) => (
           <button type="submit" 
                   className={'btn btn-outline-dark btn-md'} 
                   key={item.name}
                   onClick = {() => setToggle(wantedGraph(item.name))}
                   >
               {item.name}
           </button>
            ))}
                <div>
                  { toggle }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

`

Currently nothing is showing inside of the component.

The page works perfectly and the buttons are there.
UseState is also working, but as soon as you press on a button, the component doesn't render.

I should add that I'm also using Graph.js and each component is in a different page and i'm importing all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting `toggle`'s value to `undefined` in your button's `onClick` handler. It is getting set to `undefined` because `wantedGraph` returns the value gotten from calling `setToggle`, which does not return anything, i.e. `undefined`.

You should either change `wantedGraph` to return the component you want, e.g.:

```
const wantedGraph = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case "EOQ":
        return <EOQgraph />
      case "ROP":
        return <ROPgraph />
    }
  }
```

Or change the `onClick` handler to not call `setToggle`:

```
return (
    <div>
      {navigation.map((item) => (
        <button type="submit"
          className={'btn btn-outline-dark btn-md'}
          key={item.name}
          onClick={() => wantedGraph(item.name)}
        >
          {item.name}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div style={{ color: 'white' }}>
        {toggle}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second method and now its working well. but now another issue is coming regarding rendering the componenets EOQgraph and ROPgraph. It says: ReferenceError: Line is not defined. Even though I've already installed Chartjs, and it was working normally when I tried it out previously. Do you think you know why this is happening?